# OpenGL context on the iphone. What does it do / how does it work?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have been trying to understand OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone for quite a while, I have been able to make it work some how. But there is something I really can't understand very well. What is the OpenGL context? or what is it for?

I know opengl wont work without creating one. But I would like someone to tell me what it is exactly.

Because when doing OpenGL stuff you even have to make sure that the EAGL context is the current one. Since I haven't had the necessity of creating others I have never payed attention to making sure it is the current one.

Also do i create just one and pass it around?

Do I have to destroy it If i am gonna stop using OpenGL?

How come I can make the context pointer from an object (like an glkview) point to my created EAGL context? Is it object specific?

I know it might be a very weird question but even though I tried looking for the answer in google or here I couldn't find a concise answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenGL context encapsulates the entire state of an instance of OpenGL. So creating a context is the way to initialise OpenGL and setting a context is necessary for the system to be able to make sense of the names you later cite for textures, frame buffers, etc. So an obvious use of multiple contexts is simply to encapsulate OpenGL state, rather than letting everything become implicitly global.

OpenGL is a highly modal API and hence prima facie not unsafe for threading. However, contexts associate only with a single thread and iOS allows sharegroups, which are collections of contexts that can use the same named resources (subject to some minor manual synchronisation). So far and away the most common use of multiple contexts is to allow a background to prepare an expensive resource (such as loading a large texture) without interrupting the user experience on the main thread.

You should destroy a context if you're done with it to allow resources to be returned to the system. `GLKView`s take a context at init and expose their current context for getting and setting via the `context` property.